# Have a single useEffect hook after any component has been rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So I have my routes that render a component:

```
const Layout = () => {

  return (
    <InitLayout>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from='/' to='/home/recent' />
        <Route path="/home/:category" exact component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About}></Route>
        <Route path="/help" exact component={Help}></Route>
        <Route path="/users/:userId" exact component={UserProfile}></Route>
        <Route path="/ask" exact component={AskQuestion}></Route>
        <Route path="/review" exact component={ReviewPost}></Route>
        <Route path="/posts/:postId/review" exact component={ReviewPost}></Route>
        <Route path="/users/:userId" exact component={UserProfile}></Route>

        <Redirect from='*' to='/home/recent' />
      </Switch>
    </InitLayout>
  );
};
```

In any of these components I would theoretically set the following effect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isSsr) {
      fetchPosts();
    }
    setSsrState({ isSsr: false }); // ==> Here 
  }, []);
```

This code will basically set an SSR state, to prevent the client to re-request data from the server when it has already been preloaded from the server.

Now this state needs to be set from any of the components, but I don't want to duplicate this code in all components. Forgetting to put it will result in bugs, so that is definitely a bad idea.

Is there a straightforward way to define an effect once, and have it called in every of the route's component?

Comment: What if you were to put the useEfffect into your layout, and use redux or context to set a global state?

Comment: @alex067 That doesn't work unfortunately, because the layout will set the ssr flag to false, before any of the components have rendered. Point of having this is to avoid needing to send the ajax request on initial render from the client.

Comment: What about using HOC for each component?

Comment: @alex067 It's a good idea, but I'm not sure if the useEffect of the child will be called before the parent. If the HOC's useEffect is called first, it will not work for the same reason. Let me try, but I'm afraid it will be the same. But I'll try, you never know it may call the child's useEffect first (could make sense).

Comment: I think HOC will call it's useEffect first, since you're wrapping the HOC around your original component, and the original component gets returned at the very end of HOC with additional data. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: @alex067 That's not good. What I need is for the SSR to be set to false, after the routed component is rendered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203782/discussion-between-trace-and-alex067).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with Trace, the issue was able to be resolved by wrapping the layout component with an HOC, which sets the SSR state to false.

Interestingly enough, by wrapping the component inside an HOC, this sets off the child components first before the HOC component. That way, we are able to first check on the child component level if the SSR is set. After the child component useEffect is ran, the HOC useEffect is then ran, which sets the SSR flag back to false.